# How can I change string "Rows per page" in material UI TablePagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to change the string ["Rows per page"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuTHN.png) in Material UI TablePagination component? I could not find anything... I just want to translate it to Portuguese to display in my website.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass `labelRowsPerPage={"Your text"}` prop to `TablePagination`.

Comment: So sad it could only customize text _before_ the select, but not after :(

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite old. At the moment you can set this property through `slotProps`. Check it out this answer: [How to change the label value from pagination in DataGrid (material ui)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74851005/how-to-change-the-label-value-from-pagination-in-datagrid-material-ui)

```
slotProps={{
   pagination: {
     labelRowsPerPage: "You custom text",
   },
}}
```

Hop it could help

Comment: If you need to change also the ```{page} of {count}``` you can use ```labelDisplayedRows``` property func which takes a paginationInfo and has to return a string that has to been shown over there. It could look like:

labelDisplayedRows: (paginationInfo) => {
       return `${paginationInfo.from} OF ${paginationInfo.count}`;
},