# How to change the label value from pagination in DataGrid (material ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using DataGrid from material-ui who give me an array with pagination and filter

```
 <DataGrid
        rows={OffersFilteredData}
        getRowId={(row) => row?._id}
        sx={{
          boxShadow: 5,
          border: 2,
          borderColor: '#fff',
          '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:hover': {
            color: 'primary.main',
          },
        }}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        selectionModel={offersChecked?.map((obj) => Object.values(obj)[0])}
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          onRowsSelectionHandler(ids);
        }}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]}
      />
```

I would like to change the label value from the pagination, but keep the DataGrid.
[image]

I have seen the possibility to make an external TablePagination component, but I would like to keep the Datagrid instead of doing separately component. Is there option that i can add to datagrid to change the label ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use componentsProps attribute and change labelRowsPerPage in the pagination

like this :

```
 <DataGrid
        rows={OffersFilteredData}
        getRowId={(row) => row?._id}
        sx={{
          boxShadow: 5,
          border: 2,
          borderColor: '#fff',
          '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:hover': {
            color: 'primary.main',
          },
        }}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        selectionModel={offersChecked?.map((obj) => Object.values(obj)[0])}
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          onRowsSelectionHandler(ids);
        }}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]}
        componentsProps={{
          pagination: {
            labelRowsPerPage: "new label for rows per page",
          }
         }}
      />
```

here is a codesandbox that I changed it's label

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-antonelli-kp88le?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by overriding a special DataGrid prop: `slotProps`

```
<DataGrid
    rows={OffersFilteredData}
    getRowId={(row) => row?._id}
    sx={{
        boxShadow: 5,
        border: 2,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        '& .MuiDataGrid-cell:hover': {
            color: 'primary.main',
        },
    }}
    columns={columns}
    checkboxSelection
    selectionModel={offersChecked?.map((obj) => Object.values(obj)[0])}
    onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
        onRowsSelectionHandler(ids);
    }}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]}
    slotProps={{ pagination: { labelRowsPerPage: 'Your defined label here' } }}
/>
```

You can find more detailed information [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#overriding-components).